# use of case in order to retrieve an aggregate using a wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to select the sum of c.[weight] where dc.description is different. I am looking to do 5 cases like : case when dc.description like 'failed%' then calculate the sum of the c.[consignment reference].

How would I do this?

```
 SELECT lpr.RegID, lpr.Reg,
                        SUM(c.[Weight]) AS LeftOffWt
                FROM    dbo.whsCo wc
                        INNER JOIN whsHe wh on wh.WhsHeaderID = wc.whsHeaderID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.cgtCo c ON c.[Consignment Reference] = wc.ConsignmentReference
                        INNER JOIN dbo.disCo dc on dc.ConsignmentRef = wc.ConsignmentReference
                        INNER JOIN dbo.genA ga ON ga.AddressID = c.Consignor
                        INNER JOIN dbo.lpra lp ON lp.Postcode = ga.PostcodePrefix
                        INNER JOIN dbo.lstPos lpr ON lpr.RegionID = lp.RegionID
                                                          AND c.Cancelled = 0
                WHERE   wc.StatusCode IN ( 'NL' ) and wh.ArrDepDate between @StartDate and @EndDate and dc.Description like '%failed%'
                GROUP BY lpr.RegionID, lpr.Region
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation -- that is, make the `CASE` the argument to the aggregation function `SUM()`:

```
SELECT lpr.RegID, lpr.Reg,
       SUM(c.[Weight]) AS LeftOffWt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dc.description like 'failed%' THEN c.[consignment reference] ELSE 0 END) AS sum_failed,
       . . .
. . .
```

You also need to remove the condition from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I get this error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: @Diana . . . There is no such expression in my answer.  Nor is any such expression implied by this code.